# Как я могу сделать этот hover transition?

Tags: css, css3, html5, css-animation

Я пытаюсь повторить этот `transition` с сайта uber.design:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что я застрял в обратном `transition`:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54616139/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все хорошо, но лучше такое решать через before и after, есть возможность перемещать объекты, навешивать анимации итп. Если сделать два псевдокласса то можно сделать так как будто рамка растет вокруг и пропадает также.

Описание подходов решения (варианты не единственные это только примеры):
Вводное: Все объекты, а именно div и span преобразованы в `inline-block`, что позволит встраивать их в любое место, без переноса строк, а также добавлены `padding` для отступов, курсор ассоциируется в `poiner` и **самое главное** для этих примеров задано **относительное позиционирование** `position: relative`

Далее по отдельным примерам:

1. Добавляем блоку псевдоэлемент `after` который позволит создать далее варианты анимации (1,2,3) этот объект позиционируется `absolute` слева внизу с шириной в 2px и длинной на весь объект. После остается добавить только вариант анимации, для того чтобы анимация была плавной используем `transition` задав время анимации в 300ms и отслеживая только свойство `transform` которое и будет производить анимацию. Последним действием навешиваем `transform: scaleX(0)` что уменьшит объект на 0 по оси абсцисс (X) для того чтобы анимация была из угла в угол зададим трансформацию от правого нижнего угла(точнее им закончится) `transform-origin: right bottom`. Последний шаг добавим действия при наведении мышки на родителя, путем задания `scaleX(1)` и для того чтобы казалось что процесс идет с противоположного угла пока мышка над родителем задается точка трансформирования нижний левый угол.
2. Пример тот же что и первый за исключением того что правый угол верхний склуглен и задана высота 100%. Что позволило сделать эффект выползания и уползания червя )))
3. Третий пример повторяет второй, только не имеет скругления и позиционируется вверху.
4. Чуть более усложнен, добавлен еще один элемент `before` который анимируется уже по вертикали. Что позволяет сделать рост их угла.
5. Это еще один вариант решения, в котором для выполнения анимации добавлены 4 элемента span, данных элементов может быть и больше все зависит от задачи. Данные элементы прижаты к краям поочередно, т.к. не задан `transform-origin` они растут изменяю размер относительно своего центра.

```css
div, span{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
div::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}
div:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

div.second::after{
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
}
div.second:hover::after{
  transform: scale(1, 0.1);
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

div.third::after{
  transform-origin: right top;
  height: 100%;
}
div.third:hover::after{
  transform: scale(1, 0.1);
  transform-origin: left top;
}

span.four::after, span.four::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}
span.four::before{
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 0);
  transform-origin: righ bottom;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

span.four:hover::after, span.four:hover::before{
  transform: scale(1);
}

span.five span{
  transition: transform 300ms;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

span.five span:nth-child(odd){
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

span.five span:nth-child(even){
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
}

span.five span:nth-child(1){
  left: 0;
}
span.five span:nth-child(2){
  left: 0;
}
span.five span:nth-child(3){
  right: 0;
}
span.five span:nth-child(4){
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

span.five:hover span{
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

```html
<div>try me</div>
<div class="second">try me2</div>
<div class="third">try me3</div>
<hr>
<span class="four">квадрат</span>
<span class="five">
  квадрат
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Semenov смотрится интересно, темы с подчеркиванием и рамками были, причем в самых разных вариантах. Поэтому просто необходимо, чтобы вы более подробно описали свою технику решения.  Варианты решения `try me2`, `try me 3` смотрятся, как-то неоднозначно,- красные, толстые  хвосты появления и исчезновения линии лучше бы, как-то убрать. Или вы считаете это фишкой решения?

Comment: Да второй был как червь ))) Я так и думал он типа выполз и уполз ))) Третий изначально делал треугольником, не понравилось, а так это просто варианты, каждый может менять css и добиться своих эффектов, просто вариантов больше чем с backlound. Тем более если нужно будет анимировать картинку.

Comment: Semenov комментировать более подробно свою техник будете?

Comment: Каких именно? Или всех?

Comment: Semenov ну мне лично не нужны комментарии. Я хочу, чтобы новичкам было понятно. А без пояснений, голый код для новичков, это просто демонстрация своих знаний :)  Так что считаете нужным и полезным пояснить, то и добавьте в комментариях. [вот для примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947243/28748)

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать бордер при помощи псевдоэлемента `after`, и изначально сделать его нулевой ширины и прижать к правому краю `right: 0`, а при ховере уже `left: 0` и изменять ширину на 100%. Таким образом произойдет следующее:

- при наведении бордер нулевой ширины прижмется влево и начнет плавно увеличиваться до 100%
- при уведении курсора бордер вновь прижмется вправо и плавно уменьшится обратно до 0
- соответственно, если поменять `left` и `right` местами, то эффект будет в обратную сторону

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  transition: 300ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

Comment: я две галочки поставить не могу :) Есть ещё один переводной топик, там совсем просто ответить. Условия те же  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/947296/28748

Answer (score 3):

- Вы можете использовать градиент и отрегулировать
  `background-position` с задержкой, чтобы получить такой эффект:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-position: 0 100%; /*OR bottom left*/
  background-size: 0% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition:
    background-size 0.3s,
    background-position 0s 0.3s; /*change after the size immediately*/
}

.un:hover {
  background-position: 100% 100%; /*OR bottom right*/
  background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

- Если вам нужна непрерывная анимация при наведении, вы можете
  попробовать это:

```css
.un {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  background-position: right -100% bottom 0;
  background-size: 200% 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.un:hover {
  background-position: left -100% bottom 0;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<span class="un">Underlined Text</span>
```

Для более подробной информации вы можете прочитать  ответ о том, как выполняется вычисление другого значения:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333