# html - эффект наведения: сделать один div поверх другого div

Tags: css, jquery, html5, css-animation

Я хочу создать следующий эффект наведения: при `hover` один `div (.left)` должен расширяться до полной ширины и покрывать другой `div (.right)`.

Это то, что я до сих пор сделал:     https://jsfiddle.net/Kubismus/tcm8nzu2/4/

```js
$(".container").css({'height':($("img").height()+'px')});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 67%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}

.container:hover .left {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
     <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddofbxz8d/image/upload/v1548087392/ka6fgbjakjeskramtkew.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Объяснение / Требования:**

Изображение имеет соотношение сторон 1:1. Высота `div .container` должна определять высоту изображения, которое, в свою очередь, должно иметь ширину 33% от `div .container.`

**Проблемы**

Почему изображение сдвигается вниз, хотя его `z-index` установлен в `-1`?

Я пробовал несколько разных подходов, которые  нашел в Интернете, но они не работают в моем случае.

Например, я не хочу устанавливать позицию `div .right` в `position: absolute`, поскольку я игнорирую заполнение `div .container`.

Как я могу решить эту проблему?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [html - hover effect: make div flow above another div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54732712/7394871) от участника  [@newman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8952749/newman).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54732712/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рассмотрим отрицательное `margin`, чтобы избежать переноса изображения на следующую строку. Вы также можете упростить свой код, используя `flexbox` вместо `float`, и вам больше не понадобится код `JS` для установки высоты:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /*it will work even wrap enabled*/
}

.left {
  width: 67%;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,0.8);
  transition:1s;
}

.right {
  width: 33%;
  z-index:-1;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
}

.container:hover .left {
  margin-right:-33%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
     <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/ddofbxz8d/image/upload/v1548087392/ka6fgbjakjeskramtkew.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [html - hover effect: make div flow above another div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54732748/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>